# Why does my phone charge/discharge quickly when charged in a car a using cigarette lighter charging adapter?

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, charging, discharge, battery-lifespan

I have observed that when I charge my phone through a cigarette lighter charging adopter in a car, it charges up quickly and discharges quickly too. The same phone charges and discharges slowly when charged with a mobile charger. Why is that so?

If the battery gets fully charged quickly, why does it drain quickly too? This seems to kill the purpose of fast charging in the first place. I think that it also reduces the efficiency of mobile battery considering the fact that Li-ion batteries are way more sensitive when compared to lead acid batteries.

Comment: Sounds like some sort of false indication. In my experience devices charge at exactly the same speed in car vs at home.  Are you using the *phone's* opinion on how charged it is?  Or the charger's?  Of course home chargers tend to be UL-Listed (or other responsible testing lab) whereas most car chargers are super-cheap garbage off Alibaba.

Comment: Discharge rate is based on how you use it: more use = quicker discharge.

Comment: some chargers are capable of "fast charging", others are not. Since you are using 2 different chargers it's not meaningful to blame the car-charger vs. other charger. Also, discharging has nothing to do with chargers - it depends on how you use it. However fast discharging could ALSO be due to your battery being old or otherwise having deteriorated

Comment: @SolarMike, yes. Discharge rate is indeed based on the use. I was surprised because my phone is new (purchased a couple of months ago, meaning the battery is in good health) and I know at what pace the battery drains because I use it daily. I observed weird discharge rate surprisingly only when battery charges quickly (otherwise the battery works fine when using social media, playing games, using hotspot, LTE, etc.) and I was trying to figure out why is that so.